# Multiple duplicate content generate when using Batch process

Tags: joomla3.0

[duplicate content generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usY17.jpg)

Multiple copies of an article are generated when choosing a category and using the "Copy" option in the Batch process in Article Manager in Joomla 3.9.10. How can I resolve this issue? Please see attached.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error in Joomla 3.9.10 but you could file a bug report. See https://docs.joomla.org/Filing_bugs_and_issues for details. You could also ask this question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com